# Ways to people can get exactly 4 beers

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $b ≥ 1$ and $c ≥ 1$ be integers. Elisa’s neighborhood pub serves $b$ different types of
>   beer and $c$ different types of cider. Elisa invites $6$ friends to this pub and orders $7$ drinks,
>   one drink (beer or cider) for each friend, and one cider for herself. Different people may get
>   the same type of beer or cider.
>   In how many ways can Elisa place these orders, such that exactly $4$ people get a beer?
>
> **Answer: ${6\choose4} \cdot b^4 \cdot c^3$**

Why do we do ${6\choose4}$ here? I can understand that $b^4$ is the number of ways you can distribute the beers to $4$ people, but if we then do $c^3$ thats $3$ ways to distribute $3$ ciders (including Elisa) which makes for $7$ people. Also why do we do $c^3$ when we have already reserved one cider for Elisa?

Comment: $c^3$ isn't counting the number of ways to distribute 3 ciders to the 3 cider-getting people. It's counting the number of ways that the 3 cider getting people could end up picking their ciders. Elisa has $c$ options, Cider Friend 1 has $c$ options, and Cider Friend 2 has $c$ options, giving us $c^3$ ways in which the three of them could get ciders.

Comment: How would this question change if we took Elisa out of the picture? Ie. 7 people order 7 drinks, 4 of which must be beers. Is it enough to say $b^4 \cdot c^3$ since we are not choosing 'which' people get beer?

Comment: If the friends have identities (i.e. person 1 is distinct from person 2), it'd be $\binom{7}{4} \cdot b^4 \cdot c^3$. If the friends don't have identities, then it is only the collection of beers and ciders that matter. Then (I'm pretty sure that) the answer would be $\left({{b}\choose {4}}\right) \left({{c}\choose {3}}\right)$, where the double parentheses refer to [multichoose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\binom{6}{4}$ is the number of ways to choose the 4 of Elisa's friends who will get a beer.

$b^4$ is the number of ways those 4 friends can choose their beers: Each of those friends can choose one of $b$ different beers, so there are $b^4$ different assignments of friends to beers.

$c^3$ is the number of ways Elisa and the two cider-getting friends can get their drinks, since c is the number of choices of ciders that each person who receives cider has.

Putting this all together gives you $$\binom{6}{4}\cdot b^4 \cdot c^3. $$

Comment: Thank you. So, would this be the same as saying: ${6\choose4} \cdot b^4 \cdot {2\choose2} \cdot c^2 \cdot c$? This way, we can see that 4 arbitrary friends have $b$ ways to order their 4 beers, then for the remaining arbitrary 2 friends, there are $c$ ways order 2 their ciders, then there is of course $c$ ways Elisa can choose her own cider which, when simplified, is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Elisa must order a cider, thus we need to choose $4$ out of her friends to order beer. Which gives $\binom{6}{4} $ choices. For each of those $\binom{6}{4} $ choices, we must decide on the type of beer. Each choice implies $4$ orders of beer and $3$ orders of cider, which is where the answer came from.
Hence, to address your questions specifically, we have $\binom{6}{4} $ because we can choose which $4$ of her $6$ friends order beer. In addition, no matter which $4$ friends we choose to buy beer, we still have c choices of cider for the other $2$ friends, and Elisa of course, can have c choices of cider. The main thing is, we have already reserved a cider, but we didn't reserve a specific cider for her. She still has $c$ choices nevertheless.